# No route matches [POST] "/contacts/new" Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-3, cloud9-ide

I'm building an interactive website through Cloud9 using a tutorial online. We are using bootstrap, JavaScript, ruby on rails, html, and scss. However, I am currently stuck. Whenever I click 'submit'...I get a `Routing Error page`. None of the information is stored in my db.

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root to: 'pages#home'
  get 'about', to: 'pages#about'
  resources :contacts
end
```

**contacts_controller.rb**

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @contact = Contact.new
  end

  def create
    @contact = Contact.new(contact_params)
    if @contact.save
      redirect_to new_contact_path, notice: "Message sent."
    else
      redirect_to new_contact_path, notice: "Error occured."
    end
  end

  private
    def contact_params
      params.require(:contact).permit(:name, :email, :comments)
    end
 end
```

**contacts/new.html.erb**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <h3 class="text-center">Contact Us</h3>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
      <%= flash[:notice] %>
      <div class="well">
        <%= form_for "contact" do |f| %>
          <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :name %>
            <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :email %>
            <%= f.text_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :comments %>
            <%= f.text_area :comments, class: 'form-control' %>
          </div>
          <%= f.submit 'Submit', class: 'btn btn-default' %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I followed the instructions exactly, and I have no idea what is wrong or what to change. Can someone help before I rip my hair out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change

```
<%= form_for "contact" do |f| %>
```

to

```
<%= form_for @contact do |f| %>
```

Full code

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <h3 class="text-center">Contact Us</h3>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
      <%= flash[:notice] %>
      <div class="well">
        <%= form_for @contact do |f| %>
          <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :name %>
            <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :email %>
            <%= f.text_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :comments %>
            <%= f.text_area :comments, class: 'form-control' %>
          </div>
          <%= f.submit 'Submit', class: 'btn btn-default' %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```